# node package manager giving error when using command

Tags: node.js, npm

This problem has been with me for a bit over a day now and really can't find a solution online, nor someone else who has a problem similar to it.  I am using node v8.7.0 and whenever I try to run `npm i` or any `npm` command it gives an error saying

```
 C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �♦
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:15:20)
```

I am really not sure what the problem is here because the arrow is pointing to some strange characters.  Also when I try running the command `node` it works fine and runs files fine it is just npm that is giving me the error.  I have tried restarting my computer after reinstalling node about 3 times (v8.7.0, v9.0.0, and v6.11.4) and they all give me this error.

Comment: Have you tried to clear your node cache at all? `npm cache clear`  and delete `~/.npm` (or wherever npm is stored for you)?

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes I tried both but still giving the same npm error as above